# GoogleMaps markers and CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, core-data, marker

I'm writing an application that allows the user to have an array of images associated with a Google Maps marker. I am storing the image array in the marker's userData property. I want the markers to be persistent between app uses, so I am currently trying to store them in CoreData. However, it does not seem like CoreData allows me to store GMSMarker objects as they are, and I'm having a difficult time trying to find a way around that. I was wondering if anyone could point me in the direction of the easiest way to store the markers or marker location/information in CoreData, or some other persistent storage?

I'm new to GoogleMaps and CoreData, so any help is greatly appreciated!